# Delphi RAR Component requesting a password for archive

Tags: delphi, passwords, components, archive, rar

I want to the this RAR component: http://www.philippewechsler.ch/RARComponent.php
By Philippe Wechsler.

But I don't understand how can I request a password NOT for files in an archive but for an ARCHIVE?

It is written in the documentation that I don't understand how to use:

```
OnPasswordRequired(Sender: TObject; const HeaderPassword: Boolean; 
const FileName: WideString;out NewPassword: Ansistring; out Cancel: Boolean);
```

This event occurs if a password is required to continue.

`HeaderPassword`: if this is true, the password is required to open the archive.
Otherwise the password is needed to process a file.

`FileName`: the filename of the file that requires a password (either the archivename
or the filename of the file inside the archive)

`NewPassword`: the required password

`Cancel`: set this to true if you don’t know the correct password

How do I use this code?

Comment: @Michael, have you tried emailing the author? There's an email link on this page: http://www.philippewechsler.ch/About.php

Answer (score 1):

```
OnPasswordRequired(Sender: TObject; const HeaderPassword: Boolean; 
const FileName: WideString;out NewPassword: Ansistring; out Cancel: Boolean);
```

I'm not sure what the question is here... This is an event handler, and you assign it just as you would any other event handler: either by double-clicking the `OnPasswordRequired` event in the Object Inspector, or by connecting it via code:

```
implementation

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    RARComp.OnPasswordRequired := RARPasswordRequired;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.RARPasswordRequired(Sender: TObject; 
    const HeaderPassword: Boolean; 
    const FileName: WideString; 
    out NewPassword: Ansistring; out Cancel: Boolean);
  begin
    if HeaderPassword then  // need whole archive password
      NewPassword := YourWholeArchivePassword  // provide whole archive password
    else
      // Need individual file password. If you have a separate password for
      // each file, provide it as each file is provided in "filename" param.
      if FileName = TheFilenameYouHavePasswordFor then
        NewPassword := ThisFilesPassword
      else
        Cancel := True;
  end;
```

I have no idea what the component name would be (I used `RARComp`, but I'm not familiar with this component); replace it with whatever is correct. There's surely a predefined type for the `OnPasswordRequired` event (like `TPasswordRequiredEvent` or something); again, I'm not familiar with the component.

To explain: The `out` parameters passed to the event handler are like `var` parameters, except they don't have to be initialized before being passed by the component. The fact they are `out` means they are **output**; you're expected to assign values to them. The two `const` parameters (`HeaderPassword` and `FileName`), on the other hand, can't be changed by you; they are values for your use in deciding how to set the two parameters you are allowed to change. The `Sender` will be the `RARComp` or whatever your component instance is called; it can be typecast if needed to access other information using syntax like `TRARComponent(Sender)` or `(Sender as TRARComponent)`.

Again, I have no idea what the proper classname is for this component, or what your instance of it would be named. If the classname of the component is `TRARComponent` on the IDE's component palette, and you drop it on the form, it would be declared as `RARComponent1: TRARComponent;`, and you would use the name `RARComponent1` and `TRARComponent(Sender)` where appropriate.

Comment: this component (RAR Component v.2.0): http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=300
Author

What happens (see demo): if you type a wrong password then

Comment: this component (RAR Component v.2.0): http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=300

Author`s code:
 procedure TMainForm.RARArchivePasswordRequired(Sender: TObject;
  const HeaderPassword: Boolean; const FileName: WideString;
  out NewPassword: string; out Cancel: Boolean);
begin
  Cancel := not InputQuery('Password required for '+extractFileName(FileName),extractFileName(FileName),NewPassword);
end;

What happens (see demo): if you type a wrong password all time it will stop to ask the pass - no files left. I need a query not for files but for all archive.

Comment: @Michael: I'm sorry. Is there no 'bad password' event? Is there no exception raised on a bad password? I'm not sure what your question is now, or what you expect at this point. I've answered the question you asked, which was how to use the event `OnPasswordRequired`. If you're now asking another question, it should be asked separately; if your actual question is different than what I answered, you should edit the original question so that it actually asks what you want to know.

Comment: The password for the entire archive is required when `HeaderPassword` is true when the event is called, and I answered that already.

Comment: Ken White, is it normal if you put a wrong password the component will stop working without a new query? This issue is in the demo of author and I do not know how to correct it.

Comment: @Michael: I'd expect it to stop working if it wants an archive password and you give it the wrong one. How it "stops working", I don't know; I don't use the component. What does "stop working" mean? Does it raise an exception, or do something else? Does it return false from the decompress, unrar or whatever method? If you define what "stops working" means, maybe someone can help. I don't use the component, and don't want to download it, find a password protected RAR, and spend the time answering the questions you won't provide the answers to despite several tries from me.

Comment: @Michael: I think this question  has run it's course. Your question was "How do I use the OnRequirePassword event?", which has been answered. You now have a new question: "How do I deal with a wrong password being entered?" - I think you should ask a new question about this, and provide information about what it's doing now with a wrong password and how you'd like it to respond instead.

Comment: A asked "But I don't understand how can I request a password NOT for files in an archive but for an ARCHIVE?" I stall want to apply the pass not for files but for archive.

Comment: @Michael: **Read** my code in the answer, particularly the part `if HeaderPassword then NewPassword := YourWholeArchivePassword` - see the `NewPassword := YourWholeArchivePassword` section? This statement shows you how to give the password for the ARCHIVE, not for files. If you're not going to read the answers, it's hard to help you.

Comment: How to make a query for pass I know, there is a demo. My question - how to make a query not for files, but for an archive. Your answer is general knowledges, I know what parameters mean and how to work with them. I think that an answer is not related to OnPasswordRequired, I need to set const HeaderPassword to true.